# "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined" when using dotenv in a module

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, dotenv

I'm attempting to import/install dotenv into my project but I keep getting an odd error. Due to my `package.json` having `"type":"module"`, I am importing dotenv as follows

```
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();
import express from 'express';
```

Despite this, after building, running `npm run serve` and then viewing the project in a browser, I am getting this error:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`

with the error referring to the `main.js` file within the dotenv package itself. Am I missing a step here?

Comment: No you don't, you get _way_ more information than that, so remember to show the full error =)  That said though, why would your browser code be loading dotenv? That's server code.

Comment: Not sure what you're implying? Here's the full error in its entirety 
```Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at main.js:1:12
(anonymous) @ main.js:1```

Comment: Whether it's a Node or browser error, there's a stack trace.  But also: why is your browser code even set to run dotenv at all? That's code that should only run either on the server, or at bundle-time. You're going to have to add a few more details here to explain how the Node.js code you're showing is getting built for, and loaded by, the browser.

Comment: I'm importing dotenv into my project so I can access environmental variables to use in a fetch/API call. The project itself is a simple html button that uses these variables, but the import is within my controller script that handles the API calls.

Comment: The browser has no environment or filesystem to load a .env file from; dotenv can't do anything when loaded by the browser. It's a purely server-side piece of helper. You use it for running your server-side code, as well as loading it as part of your bundling task (if you have one) to load the environment and copy over any variable you need into the bundling context.

Comment: Ah, gotcha! I may be doing this entirely incorrectly then. Thanks!

Comment: To clarify, this is the case even when running ```npm run serve``` using a web dev server?

Comment: Nope: using it for that is the exact use-case that `dotenv` _is_ for. It lets our server-side scripts do what they need to do while being able to tap into (and extend) the execution environment.

Comment: Ah, that's my issue then, I'm still getting this error when running ```npm run serve```

Comment: Then you'll have to explain what `npm run serve` actually does. You're showing code in a `main.js`, which is not a the common `server.js` or `app.js` so remember to explain what kind of project this is (if you started with some kind of prebuilder) and what your npm scripts do. Bearing in mind, of course, that if this is some established project building (e.g. create react app or the like) then you should be able to find tutorials that explain how to tap into your environment variables, and the solution is to follow those, rather than fixing what you already have =)